# i am trying to compute and return primes between two given numbers but can not figure out how

Tags: java

```
     public int getPrimesWithin(int min, int max)
{
    for (int n = min; n <= max; n++)
    {
        if (nums [n] == true)
        {
            return n;
        }

    }

}
```

goes through code and returns primes is this right and what should i do next to return primes between two numbers

Comment: `if (nums [n] = true)` assigns `true` to `nums[n]` and then evaluates to `true`. You almost certainly wanted to type `==`.

Comment: Maybe you put in the code what you think each line is for and what you think is happening in each line?

Comment: The first loop doesn't make sense. You create an array (which then immediately goes out of scope) with every iteration. After the loop exits, nothing has actually been accomplished. You need to describe what you were hoping that code would do.

Comment: First loop: why do you create max - min arrays?

Comment: i can't use arraylist of prestablished methods on this one unfortunatly

Comment: Simple solution: Find an isPrime function on the internet (there are millions of them...they're easy to find, and trial division versions are just a few lines long). Loop from min to max, test each value with isPrime, and there you go.

Comment: @user2730962 arraylist or array, but what for? You do not need this arrays. Try solution written by me and hatchet. `for`/`while` loop from min to max and `if` condition to check whether choosen number is prime number.

Comment: Now array nums is undeclared. Check whether `n`, not `num[n]` is prime number and save it in the array.

Comment: Before loop add `int i=0` and collection, which is better than array in this example e.g. `ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>`. Change your condition to `if(isPrime(n)) num.add(n);` and fill method `boolean isPrime(int n)`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest algorithm requires knowing all the primes up to (and including, if it happens to be the case) `sqrt(max)`.

- Obtain/build the list of primes between 2 and `sqrt(max)`.
- Iterate all numbers `n` between `min` and `max`
- Iterate on the list of primes, testing if they divide `n`.
- If any of them does, then `n` is not a prime and the inner iteration can be terminated.
- If none of them is a divisor, then `n` is prime.

Answer (score 0):

This will always be true :

```
if (nums [n] = true)
```

I think you wanted this :

```
if (nums [n] == true)
```

Comment: Or, more conventionally, `if (nums[n])`.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
for(int i = min; i <= max; i++)
{
    int [] temp = new int [i];
}
```

By the time it is complete, will **always** result in `temp` being an array of ints of length `max`. Also, as hatchet pointed out, once we leave the loop, we lose the array due to `temp` no longer being in scope. I would suggest using an `ArrayList`, as then you can have a variable length array.

This part:

```
if (nums [n] = true)
```

As others have pointed out, is setting `nums[n]` to `true`. You probably wanted `==`.

This line:

```
temp +=n;
```

Doesn't make much sense. You're trying to add an array and an int.

Try this out:

```
ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int n = min; n <= max; n++)
{
    if (nums[n] == true)
    {
        temp.add(n);
    }
}
```

This is assuming a few things, though.

1. That `nums` is an array of booleans that represent whether or not the index is a prime.
2. That you want to return the list of all primes and not the sum of all primes or the count of primes.

Comment: Since temp is declared inside the scope of the loop, won't there actually be NO temp variable after the loop exits?

Comment: @hatchet You're right! It's been too long since I've worked in Java.